# How to play two videos simultaneously, one in the foreground and the other in the background in flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-video-player

I want to play two videos simultaneously in flutter web, one video must play in the foreground and one in the background and I want to switch between them and the videos shouldn't pause. I am able to achieve this in Android using the mixWithOthers options, but the same isn't working in flutter web. Is there any other workaround to achieve the desired output.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you figure out a workaround?